# Change Volume on Mac programmatically

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-audio, volume

I'm looking for a not applescript way to change the system volume on Mac OS X programmatically.
I just couldn't find a solution. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: [This tutorial](http://cocoadev.com/SoundVolume) might be of assistance.

Comment: Does Apple Event count as Apple Script for you?

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at this class:

https://github.com/InerziaSoft/ISSoundAdditions

It can change system volume and make use of CoreAudio API.

An example of usage should look like this:

```
[NSSound setSystemVolume:0.5]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works with Yosemite unlike all the other libraries.

Comment: Thanks for sharing... is there a way to capture volume change as an event? I.e. the user changes the volume on the menu bar and my app wants to know.

Comment: Is it possible use Java to do that??

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody is still interested in this topic: I have adapted the great ISSoundAdditions to Swift 5 and have also made its design a bit cleaner by declaring a public interface (NSSound.systemVolume)through which you can super easily manage the system sound volume through getting and setting properties (NSSound.systemVolume and NSSound.systemVolumeIsMuted). Check it out: https://github.com/mabi99/NSSound_SystemVolumeExtension