# Set OS X volume in OS X 10.11 using Swift without using the deprecated AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData API

Tags: swift, volume, osx-elcapitan

I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290751/how-to-set-systems-master-volume-from-a-swift-app-in-osx) to set the system volume using Swift. While using the code in a playground I got warning.

> AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData was deprecated in OS X 10.11

How do I update the code for OS X 10.11?

Thanks.
:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As also suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278589/change-volume-on-mac-programmatically) to a similar Objective-C question, I'd suggest using [ISSoundAdditions](https://github.com/InerziaSoft/ISSoundAdditions), which you can call from Swift as such:

```
NSSound.setSystemVolume(0.5)
```

The implementation of `-setSystemVolume` [begins around line 113](https://github.com/InerziaSoft/ISSoundAdditions/blob/master/ISSoundAdditions.m#L113) in ISSoundAdditions.m in case you're curious of how they accomplish setting the system volume.

To clarify a factually challenged comment to my answer (since deleted, apparently), there is no use of deprecated APIs in ISSoundAdditions when compiling with the El Capitan SDK – `AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData` is not used. `AudioObjectSetPropertyData` is indeed the API one should switch to if using the deprecated `AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData`, though as you can see from the ISSoundAdditions implementation I linked to, there's a bit of work involved (hence I linked to the implementation in the first place).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I replace ´AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData´ with ´AudioObjectSetPropertyData´ also my code is working, but because the Addition you recommended is much easier to use, I'll think over implementing the Addition.
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 8):

I cannot yet comment, hence I post this as a separate answer. I have updated the great ISSoundAdditions to true Swift 5 and gave it a nice public interface, through which you manage the system volume by getting and setting a class property of NSSound– examples:

```
NSSound.systemVolume += 0.2
NSSound.systemVolumeIsMuted = true
```

As a little goodie, you can mute the system volume fading out smoothly (and non-blocking in the background):

```
NSSound.systemVolumeFadeToMute(seconds: 5.0, blocking: false)
```

Check it out: [GitHub NSSound_SystemVolumeExtension](https://github.com/mabi99/NSSound_SystemVolumeExtension)