# Capture system volume changes in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, events, volume

Reading the following advices about getting and setting system volume in osX, I use the ISSoundAdditions which works great:

[Change Volume on Mac programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278589/change-volume-on-mac-programmatically/25220019?s=1|0.2860#25220019)

and

[Set OS X volume in OS X 10.11 using Swift without using the deprecated AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953948/set-os-x-volume-in-os-x-10-11-using-swift-without-using-the-deprecated-audiohard/36954944?s=2|0.2564#36954944)

I can directly manage the system sound volume with a NSSlider (with bindings).
My question is: how can I capture the volume changed as an event (for exemple when the volume up and down keys in the keyboard ? In theses cases, my slider doesn't react.
I experimented :

```
self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "volume.systemVolume", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: &volumeContext)
```

But then I get an exception:

> Cannot update for observer XX for the key path "volume.systemVolume",
>   most likely because the value for the key "volume" has changed without
>   an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the KVO-compliance
>   of the class.

BTW, `systemVolume` property is a class property, if it matters?

Many thanks for your help

Joshua

Comment: hi joshua ,do you resolve the problem to capture system volume changes? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used (Swift 4):

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(eventFunction(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "com.apple.sound.settingsChangedNotification"),
                                           object: nil)
```

Where the function is defined like:

```
@objc func volumeChangeEvent(_ evt: NSEvent) { }
```

Comment: It works only when actuall system sound settings app is open. Once its closed and I try to use keyboard shortcuts for volume up/down it won't detect the change.