# AudioKit on macOS: get/set system device volume

Tags: swift, macos, audiokit

I've used [`AudioKit.inputDevice`](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AudioKit.html#/c:@M@AudioKit@objc(cs)AudioKit(cpy)inputDevice), [`Audiotkit.outputDevice`](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AudioKit.html#/c:@M@AudioKit@objc(cs)AudioKit(cpy)outputDevice), and friends to get get all input and output devices on my Mac, and to get/set default input and output device.

I wish to read the current volume of these devices, and to be able to set it myself, but I can't find the correct AudioKit API for doing so.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This looks like what you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255006/get-system-volume-ios

Comment: @ekscrypto `AVAudioSession` is iOS only.

Comment: oh my bad, didn’t notice the macos tag

Comment: It looks like setting output volume could be accomplished in much the same way as it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290751/how-to-set-systems-master-volume-from-a-swift-app-in-osx). Just replace the line `var defaultOutputDeviceID = AudioDeviceID(0)` with `var defaultOutputDeviceID = AudioKit.outputDevice!.deviceID` (probably using `if let` instead of force unwrapping). This doesn't seem to update the sound icon in the menu bar, but it does change the system volume on my machine.

Comment: @aaplmath Looks promising, I'll give this a shot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set systems master volume from a swift app in osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290751/how-to-set-systems-master-volume-from-a-swift-app-in-osx)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a library similar to https://github.com/InerziaSoft/ISSoundAdditions

Changing sound volume becomes as simple as:

```
[NSSound setSystemVolume:0.5]
```

--
Duplicate of: [Change Volume on Mac programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278589/change-volume-on-mac-programmatically)

Comment: That only seems to work on the default output device, I'm afraid.

Comment: Seems rather easy to target any specific device, check the code in https://github.com/InerziaSoft/ISSoundAdditions/blob/master/ISSoundAdditions.m